# Dialogflow - Slack integration

Tags: dialogflow-es, integration, chatbot, slack-api, dialogflow-cx

A few years ago I built a chatbot for Slack in Dialogflow (before it was ES and CX), and it worked fine. I'm trying to build another one at the moment (2021), but ES does not have the integration tab anymore and there seems not to be a way for connecting my Dialogflow agent to slack in a way where I can interact with it.

Does anyone have experience with this and how to get it working? I've tried connecting a CX bot with Webhooks, but it does not allow me to correspond with the app in Slack.

Any help would be appreciated, and thanks in advance.

Comment: I think Dialogflow is still providing the support for the slack channel. I can see that in My Dialogflow ES. Can you cross check once?

Comment: Thanks Dhruv, it does not show up in the left nav (my only options are Intent, Entities, Fulfilment, Validation, History, and Analytics). When i put /integrations after the agent URL it shows up as expected, but when clicking on the slack integration to start, it gives me a message saying _The service is currently unavailable._ Have you experienced anything similar? Thanks again for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

For [Dialogflow ES](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs), note that built-in [Integrations](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations) are not available in the agents created in the regions other than Global (refer to [Dialogflow ES Regionalization and data residency Limitations](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/region#limits)):

- europe-west1
- europe-west2
- australia-southeast1
- asia-northeast1

For integrations to be available in your ES agent, make sure that the region of your agent is set to `Global` (default region).

As for [Dialogflow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs), currently, there is no built-in Slack integration.

However, if you want to integrate your Dialogflow ES agent created in a non-Global region or your Dialogflow CX agent with Slack, you can create your own [Incoming webhook for Slack](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks) that manages requests and responses from Slack. Then your webhook can send requests using [Dialogflow Agent Type](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/editions#agent-types) specific detectIntent methods:

- Dialogflow CX - [detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.sessions/detectIntent) ([REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest) & [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/library/overview))
- Dialogflow ES - [detectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.agent.sessions/detectIntent) ([REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest) & [Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/libraries/overview))

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much Marc, it working now. Much appreciated.